# How to remove space before 2nd column in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Again I am here for your kind help. I have uploaded part of my document which is problematic. Here is the download link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lwj011c744nolp/space%20before%20column.docx?dl=0

If you open this document in Microsoft Word and enable "Formatting Marks", you can see that in page#1, there is no space before both of the left (1st) and right (2nd) hand columns.

But if you go to page#2, you can that there is a paragraph marks before right (2nd) hand column which is creating an empty space before column-2. If I delete this space, bullet (numbering) formatting goes away for that paragraph.

If you notice both pages (Page#1 & 2), there are column breaks after certain length of the 1st column.

My question is, if the page#1 works well and there is no empty space before 2nd column, then why this empty space is creating on the page#2?

I am trying to understand the formatting system of Microsoft Word for Column formatting.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Put the cursor at the at the beginning of the second column, then press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. The column break will be deleted.
2. Put the cursor at the beginning of the list (10.4 Identification slugs must... - the cursor must be before the I of Identification), click Layout -> Breaks -> Column. A new column break will be added and your columns will be aligned.

[image]

Comment: Well, I can see that If I keep the "before space" which is currently 12 pt for the previous paragraphs (10.1 to 10.3), then your way does not work. But if I reduce the space to 0pt, then it works as per your instruction. Why this is happening....What is the root cause actually? Here is my video screenshot link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8pfl8vigsw8qt1/2nd%20column.wmv?dl=0